# Get values from an enum into a generic List

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics

I don't know how to convert the following line from VB to C#:

```
Dim values As New List(Of T)(System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(T)))
```

My version doesn't work:

```
List<T> values = new List<T>(System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)));
```

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   has some invalid arguments

The constructor-parameter doesn't take it that way - what cast (or else) am I missing?

For clarification: It is wrapped up within the following generic method

```
public static void BindToEnum<T>()
{
    List<T> values = new List<T>(System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)));
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
List<T> list = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
                          .Cast<T>()
                          .ToList<T>();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add a `.Cast<T>()`:

```
List<T> values = new List<T>(System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post, I created myself a function to do this for me; It's great in Unit Tests when you want to loop through all values of an Enum to verify something only works on certain values.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumValues<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
}
```

Then I can use it like so:

```
var values = GetEnumValues<SomeTypeCode>();

var typesToAlwaysShow = values.Where(ScreenAdapter.AlwaysShowThisType).Select(q => (int)q).ToList();

Assert.Equal("101,102,105,205", string.Join(",", typesToAlwaysShow));
```

Comment: Can be improved by adding `where T : Enum`

Answer (score 0):

From .NET 5 onwards, this is supported on `Enum` already through `Enum.GetValues<T>`, albeit it returns `T[]` instead of `List<T>`.

[Documentation is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-8.0#system-enum-getvalues-1)

A simple example.

```cs
public enum Direction
{
    Up = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Down = 2,
    Left = 3
}

// In some method...
Enum.GetValues<Description>() // returns Description[]
```